# List of Two-Mora Ichidan Verbs

Tags: words, verbs, ichidan-verbs

I've been looking for an exhaustive list of them, but I can't seem to find one in English. So far I've got these:

- いる/居る
- 得る
- 出る
- 似る
- 煮る
- 寝る
- 着る
- 干る
- 鋳る
- 射る
- 癒る
- 経る/歴る
- みる's variants, 見る/観る/視る/診る/看る

Are there any more out there?

Comment: Your list concords with https://www.akenotsuki.com/kyookotoba/shiryoo/bunrui/dooshi21.html, although it has one more — 率る.

Comment: FYI: http://quattro.phys.sci.kobe-u.ac.jp/nishi/verb.html and https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1449541019

Comment: Alright, found out about 沃る and 率る, thanks. How do we close the thread now?

Comment: If you'd like, you can answer your own question with the complete list, then you can turn it into a Community answer. I didn't create a separate answer because your list is essentially already complete.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any verbs to contribute, but I do have a question. Why would someone want a list of two-mora ichidan verbs? Are they significant in some way, apart from just being a bit rare?

Comment: @charlemagne It's because all ichidan verbs that have three or more morae have to be written with -iru or -eru in their okurigana. This does not apply to two-mora ones, as the i/e is in the kanji. So any verb outside of these ones whose okurigana ends in just -ru is a godan one regardless of whether it phonetically ends in -iru/-eru. That's why I was looking for an exhaustive list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to this list, there are also 沃る and 率る. That would seem to be all of them.

Here are some Japanese pages listing two-mora verbs, shared by jogloran and sundowner:
https://www.akenotsuki.com/kyookotoba/shiryoo/bunrui/dooshi21.html

http://quattro.phys.sci.kobe-u.ac.jp/nishi/verb.html

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1449541019